# TypeError: ('Not JSON Serializable:', <tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement multi-task CNN using adaptive `loss_weight`, which decays as the epoch increases. I referred to this [Github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2595).

```
# callback for adaptive loss_weight
class LossWeightCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, alpha):
        self.alpha = alpha
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.alpha = self.alpha * 0.9

# initial loss_weight
alpha = K.variable(10)

# model
img_input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name='input')
...
model = Model(inputs=img_input, outputs=[y1, y2])

# compile
model.compile(keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9), 
              loss={'output1': 'categorical_crossentropy', 'output2': 'mse'},
              loss_weights={'output1': 1, 'output2': alpha},
              metrics={'output1': 'accuracy', 'output2': 'mse'})

# Fit model
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint('multitask_model.h5', monitor='val_output1_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
results = model.fit(x_train, {'output1': y_train1, 'output2': y_train2}, 
                    validation_split=0.1, batch_size= 100, epochs=50, 
                    callbacks=[checkpointer, LossWeightCallback(alpha)])
```

But this code returns an error after the 1st epoch ends:

```
TypeError: ('Not JSON Serializable:', <tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>)
```

Is there any solution to this error?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a perfect answer, but when I remove `checkpointer` from `callbacks` in `model.fit()` like below, the error vanished and the code worked well.

```
results = model.fit(x_train, {'output1': y_train1, 'output2': y_train2}, 
                    validation_split=0.1, batch_size= 100, epochs=50, 
                    callbacks=[LossWeightCallback(alpha)])
```

It seems that `on_epoch_end()` function conflicts when `ModelCheckpoint` and custom callbacks are used...

Comment: Obviously it will solve the problem because Keras will not try to serialize the `K.variable`... It's not a valid answer. There's a bug in Keras

Comment: There's no conflict, AFAIK. I am also getting this error. Variables are currently apparently not JSON serializable. That's it. Unfortunately, Keras and TensorFlow are full of bad and buggy APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I also had this problem and luckily found an simple solution. In type error, it's `tf.variable` that can't be json serializable so just try to let it not be type of `tf.variable`. Please replace the original compile codes with the folowing:

```
model.compile(keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9), 
              loss={'output1': 'categorical_crossentropy', 'output2': 'mse'},
              loss_weights={'output1': 1, 'output2': alpha.numpy()},
              metrics={'output1': 'accuracy', 'output2': 'mse'})
```